# Criação do repositório SVN - Linux Mint, Apache Subversion

Tags: svn

Estou tentando seguir o [Quick-start](http://subversion.apache.org/quick-start), para executar os seguintes comandos e criar o repositório SVN local:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.svnrepos/
$ svnadmin create ~/.svnrepos/my-repos
$ svn mkdir -m "Create directory structure." file://$HOME/.svnrepos/my-repos/trunk file://$HOME/.svnrepos/my-repos/branches file://$HOME/.svnrepos/my-repos/tags
$ cd my-directory
$ svn checkout file://$HOME/.svnrepos/my-repos/trunk ./
$ svn add --force ./
$ svn commit -m "Initial import"
$ svn up
```

Onde, $HOME aqui é "/home/danilo". Pois no "/home" por padrão da instalação ficam as pastas de cada usuário.

Daí dá erro quando executo "svn mkdir". Ou seja, no terceiro passo. Como segue:

```
svn mkdir -m "Create directory structure." file://$HOME/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/trunk file://$HOME/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/branches file://$HOME/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/tags

svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///home/danilo/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos'
svn: E180001: Não foi possível abrir uma sessão ra_local para URL
svn: E180001: Não foi possível abrir repositório 'file:///home/danilo/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos'
```

Comment: Já tentou sem o `file://` na frente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado no comentário do @CiganoMorrisonMendez, fui tentar fazer o mesmo procedimento sem usar o "file://". Não deu certo, porém continuei insistindo e cheguei na seguinte solução com sucesso:

```
svn mkdir -m "Create directory structure." file:///home/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/trunk file:///home/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/branches file:///home/danilo/.svnrepos/my-repos/tags

Committed revision 1.
```

Então a solução foi que ao invés de usar:

```
file://$HOME/danilo/.svnrepos/...
```

Tive que usar:

```
file:///home/danilo/.svnrepos/...
```

Ou seja, tirei no caso o "//$HOME" e coloquei "///home/danilo".

Obs: Pelo que percebi o "$HOME" equivale na verdade a "/home/danilo". O mesmo vale para "~/". Noob.

Recomendo a leitura da documentação disponibilizada no [Apache Subversion Doc](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/), principalmente a versão em português [defasada] do [SVN-Book](https://code.google.com/p/svnbook-pt-br/).

A versão disponível em português que baixei é a que cobre a versão 1.4 do SVN. Está excelente, em linguagem bem simplificada e didática.